# Python TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Tags: python, typeerror, nonetype

So for my first big python project I'm building a text based game. It's supposed to be modular so the story and items etc. can be edited and replaced with little editing of the actual source code. Basically, the user command is stored as a string which is immediately broken into a list. The first element is an action like 'inspect' and the second element is a pseudo-argument for that action like 'location' or 'item'. After the command is interpreted, it goes to the execution module called 'item_or_loc' It's here that I get the error. Can anyone help? I'll provide more info or the entire source code if it'll help.

Command module:

```
    def item_or_loc(iolo):
        if iolo in items.items_f():
            print (items.iolo(1))
        elif iolo in locations.locations_f():
            print (locations.iolo(1))
        else:
            print ('Command not recognized, try again.')


    def location(loco):
        plo_l = PlayerClass #(player location object_location)
        if loco == 'location':
            plo_l.player_loc(0)


    def abort(abo):
        sys.exit()


    def inventory(invo):
        pio_i = PlayerClass #(player inventory object_inventory)
        if invo == 'inventory':
            pio_i.player_inv(0)
```

Items module:

```
    patient_gown=('Patient gown', 'A light blue patient\'s gown.')
    wrench=('Wrench','')
    stick=('Stick','')
    prybar=('Prybar','')
    screwdriver=('Screwdriver','')
    scalpel=('Scalpel','')
    broken_tile=('Broken tile','')
    hatchet=('Hatchet','')
    janitor_suit=('Janitor suit','')
```

Locations module: Basically the same as the Items module

Player module:

```
    import items
    import locations

    class PlayerClass:
        def player_inv(inv_index):
        pinventory = [items.patient_gown[inv_index]]
        print (pinventory)

    def player_loc(loc_index):
        ploc = [locations.cell[loc_index]]
        print (ploc)
```

Comment: Providing more context in the form of source code would be very helpful.  It's hard to help you much with just this.

Comment: How much do you want? The whole command.py module?

Comment: At least an explanation of where `items` is coming from.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan that much is clear, but debugging the problem requires knowing where items is coming from so we can see why it's None...

Comment: @Nolen clear to you and me but possibly not the asker of the question. If it were the question would be, why does `items.items_f()` return `None`.

Comment: Basically, David Heffernan is right -- but it would be nice to see the definition of `items.items_f` nonetheless. We might be able to tell you where the bug is coming from.

Comment: It's there. And yeah, I'd love an explanation because I'm a script kiddie. I started learning python... three days ago? Yeah. I have a little oop experience, but not a lot.

Comment: So dirty code, your items_f() does not returns anything.

Comment: No need to be rude, I'm super new to programming in general.

Comment: As a side note, that class probably isn't doing what you think it's doing. You have all the attributes as class attributes - that means they are shared among every instance, not unique to one object. Also, if you're using python2, be sure to make it a new-style class (Inherit from `object` - `class Player(object)`). It's not clear based on how you have your `print` statements written

Comment: Honestly, that was just something I tried to make it work. The class is gone now and items.py is just full of lists. Thanks for the input though, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

You don't return anything from `items.items_f`. You need to return a container or sequence. I would advise a different approach from the below, but it's a start, at least.

```
def items_f():
    patient_gown=('Patient gown','A light blue patient\'s gown.')
    wrench=('','')
    stick=('','')
    crowbar=('','')
    screwdriver=('','')
    scalpel=('','')
    broken_tile=('','')
    hatchet=('','')
    janitor_suit=('','')
    return (patient_gown, wrench, stick, crowbar, 
            screwdriver, scalpel, broken_tile, hatchet, janitor_suit)
```

To explain, `items_f` is not a container itself, but is rather a function (or more precisely, a method, which you can think of simply as a function "attached" to an object). Functions don't *have* to return anything, but then when you call them, the value that results from the call is simply `None`.

Now, when you do a test like `if x in y:`, `y` has to be a sequence or container type; and since you're testing the result of the function `items_f`, and since that function returns `None` as you've defined it above, the test throws an error.

The best way to handle this situation really depends on the larger structure of the program. A first step in the right direction might be something like this:

```
def items_f():
    return (('Patient gown', 'A light blue patient\'s gown.'),
            ('Wrench', 'A crescent wrench.'),
            ('Stick', '...'))
```

But that's probably not the best solution either. My suggestion based on what you've added above (which, by the way, is now missing the `items_f` function) would be to use a data structure of some kind that holds items. A simple approach would be a dictionary:

```
items = {'patient_gown':('Patient gown', 'A light blue patient\'s gown.'),
         'wrench':('Wrench', '...'),
          ...
        }
```

This creates a dictionary that contains all possible items. Now when you want a particular item, you can get it like so:

```
item = items['patient_gown']
```

This way you don't need a function at all; you can just access the whole dictionary directly.

Comment: Deleting my answer since there's not much point in two of us saying exactly the same thing.

Comment: Well I mean I'd rather not type all the item list names into a tuple or list or whatever. (I see that a tuple would probably be better since its immutable.)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, sorry I stomped on your answer; I just saw an opportunity to add more info and did so without really thinking.

Comment: @senderle It's fine. You backed it up by staying with the question and adding more and more. Well done. +1.

Comment: Well I tried adding the return function at the bottom but it ruins the 'inventory' command which basically prints the player inventory. That inventory is stored in the player.py module and inherits the item lists from items.py. When I try 'inventory' it says AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'patient_gown'. Basically, I want to be able to type 'inventory' and have it print the list of the player's inventory. I simultaneously want to type 'inspect <item>' and have it give me the description (index 1) of that item.

Comment: @SciurusDoomus, I think I need to understand more about what `items.py` is. Is it simply a module containing all possible items?

Comment: Yes, it is. Would you like me to upload the texts for all involved modules? That would involve the commands module, (gets arguments from command_interpreter) the items module, the player module, and location module.

Comment: I need 20 rep and I don't have it hahaha. Sorry. Everything is up in the original post...

Comment: @SciurusDoomus, sorry then. I added some more detail. Note that you should probably replace the `items_f` function in `items.py` so that the original question doesn't lose its meaning.

Comment: @senderle Thank you so much, that's really helpful. I'm glad the problem was with the structure of my lists rather than the rest of the program. I appreciate your help.